# Play and Stop media using JButton

Tags: java, netbeans, media

I'm creating a simple play and stop button to let user preview a song. `JButton1` is the play button while `JButton3` is supposed to be stop button. But when I clicked on the `JButton3`, the song keep playing. Is there something that can make the `jButton3` act correctly?

```
public PlayMusic() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
        if(evt.getSource()== jButton1){
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Music\\I.wav"));
        AudioStream ikon = new AudioStream(in);         
        AudioPlayer.player.start(ikon);  }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}

}
```

**jButton3ActionPerformed()**

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         try{   
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Music\\I.wav"));
        AudioStream ikon = new AudioStream(in);      
        if(evt.getSource()== jButton3)
        {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(ikon);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the same object of 'AudioStream ikon', which you are using to play, to stop the audio.

A quick dirty fix,

```
public class Myplay{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...... YOUR CODE TO FOR UI.......
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Play");
    btn1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    add(btn1); // ADD BUTTON TO JPanel
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Stop");
    btn2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    add(btn2);  // ADD BUTTON TO JPanel
  }
}

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

ButtonListener() {
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Music\\I.wav"));
AudioStream ikon = new AudioStream(in);
}

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Play")) {
      AudioPlayer.player.start(ikon);
    }
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
      AudioPlayer.player.stop(ikon);
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I suggest you do the following

```
public PlayMusic() {
initComponents();
initAudioStream();
}

AudioStream ikon;

private void initAudioStream(){
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Music\\I.wav"));
            ikon = new AudioStream(in);         
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
        if(evt.getSource()== jButton1){

        AudioPlayer.player.start(ikon);  }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}

}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         try{   
        if(evt.getSource()== jButton3)
        {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(ikon);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
}
```

Comment: Having same name for both 'AudioStream' reference variables doesn't mean the you are passing the same object. From what i see, that's all i can say. If you need more help, try posting more code.

Comment: You are not passing the SAME object, instead you are creating a new one with the same name. Check the update, this should solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!